# React native android application getting slow after some time

Tags: android, performance, react-native, couchbase-lite

I'm developing react-native redux application with native Android.

I'm using couchbase-lite as a mobile database. It syncs data in real time with Couchbase sync gateway and show data in react native UI. This application has lot of other functionalities in both react native side and android side.

App has good speed in starting time. But after some time it getting very slow. I check the heap in Android monitor if it has any memory leak, but it hasn't.

Do anyone have any idea about what is making the app slow?

Comment: Are you doing some heavy work on reactnative side ?

Comment: Yes. There is lot of code logics in reactnative side and app state is quite big.

Comment: Curious if you have tried this project for integrating with React Native: https://github.com/adamski/react-native-couchbase

Comment: Did you find the reason for this? I'm facing a similar issue!